# Declare function as variable in Javascript (or Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
$(function(){
    //choose one below at once, the results are different 
    $('#click').click(clickMe.popup);   
    $('#click').click(clickMe.popup()); 
});

 var clickMe = {
     message: 'hello',
     popup: function(){
         alert(this.message);
     }
}

<input type='button' value='click me' id='click' />
```

the results are different,

1. when I choose the first one, I get a popup when clicking the button, but it shows "undefined".
2. when I choose the second one, I automatically get a popup when loading in, and there is the "hello" message.

Question :

1. what's the different between popup() and popup ?
2. what's wrong with the message inside the popup ?

Comment: One shows what popup is (function) other invokes it, which returns undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what's the different between popup() and popup ?

`popup()` **calls** the function. `popup` just refers to it (e.g., so you can assign it as a `click` handler).

> what's wrong with the message inside the popup ?

When you hook it up as

```
$('#click').click(clickMe.popup);
```

...the click will call the function, but with `this` referring to the DOM element, not your `clickMe` object. You can use `Function#bind` to fix that:

```
$('#click').click(clickMe.popup.bind(clickMe));
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, will call the original with the `this` value you provide. If you need to support old browsers (such as IE8) that don't have `Function#bind`, jQuery provides [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) that does much the same thing:

```
$('#click').click($.proxy(clickMe.popup, clickMe));
```

...or you can just shim/polyfill `Function#bind` (a search will give you several implementations).

Comment: another question, why the popup automatically triggered when I choose the second one ? it should only happen when I click the button.

Comment: @angelyaaaaa: Because as I said above, `popup()` **calls** the function. `$('#click').click(clickMe.popup());` **calls** `clickMe.popup()` and passes its return value into `click`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.